# Tags [fcgi] and [fastcgi] need to be synonymized

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

[fcgi](/questions/tagged/fcgi) (115 questions) and [fastcgi](/questions/tagged/fastcgi) (566 questions) seem to be referring to the same thing, namely, FastCGI.

The excerpts for these tags are the same:

> FastCGI is a protocol for interfacing interactive programs with a web server. FastCGI is a variation on the earlier Common Gateway Interface (CGI); FastCGI's main aim is to reduce the overhead associated with interfacing the web server and CGI programs, allowing a server to handle more web page requests at once.

There are even [some 27 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fcgi+fastcgi) with both tags at the same time.

Can [fcgi](/questions/tagged/fcgi) be made a synonym of [fastcgi](/questions/tagged/fastcgi)?

**Update:** I now have enough rep on Stack Overflow to propose tag synonyms, but I still can't do this on my own because “creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag”.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely a duplication, and making [fastcgi](/questions/tagged/fastcgi) the real tag and [fcgi](/questions/tagged/fcgi) the alias is the best way round. Good catch.